# How to log into file in cypress?

Tags: cypress

i want to log each and every step of the process ex: sign up done, user dashboard opened , user profile edited. How can this be achieved by cypress. I tried this using node.js but as cypress runs in browser i cant create file using node.js and also i tried by cy.writefile where it replace the previous this i have written in the file. Is there a way to do this ???
After this i do want to send this log to an email.

Comment: Please show your code using `cy.writefile`

Answer (score -3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you run Cypress on a CI Server like CircleCI, it can record your output.

There is also a `--record` option, where it saves the details of the session for you.

> Cypress can record your tests running and make them available in our
>   Dashboard.
>
> Recorded tests allow you to: See the number of failed, pending and
>   passing tests. Get the entire stack trace of failed tests. View
>   screenshots taken when tests fail and when using cy.screenshot().
>   Watch a video of your entire test run or a clip at the point of test
>   failure.

You can read more about recording sessions here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Recording-tests-in-CI

Comment: This does not record each step/action to a log file, as the PO requested.  It will record a screenshot, video (if running in electron), and stack trace to the dashboard upon an error.